# android fragment using onCreateView but cant add firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a fragment in my app and I am attempting to add firebase into this fragment. But due to the face that it is using onCreateView it is calling an error on this.

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment {

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;
private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);

    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

}
```

On the mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser(); i am getting the error unreachable statement is there any way that i can still use a fragment for this activity?

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    String current_uid = Objects.requireNonNull(mCurrentUser).getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }

    return view;
    });}}
```

error on return view;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update this

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
}
```

To

```
    @Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    String current_uid = Objects.requireNonNull(mCurrentUser).getUid();

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_uid);

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
        String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
        String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
        String thumb_image = dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

    // you are calling return view inside the Value Listner that why you are getting the error
    });
    return view;
}
```

Comment: i added this and it was working at first but now appears to be causing a new error code updated.

Answer (score 0):

Just move *mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()* line before *return* statement.

Answer (score 0):

Move the below line before return statment in `onCreateView()` method.

```
 mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
```

Anything after return statement is unreachable, as error statement states.

Answer (score 0):

Let `onActivityCreated()` method handles additional job.

`ValueEventListener` is an inner class of `DatabaseReference`, hence, you don't necessary need to create object before instantiating it. So, remove the line.

Also, be reminded that `return view;` should be the last statement in your `onCreateView()`. Make sure that before closing it you have return statement.

Now do this. After `onCreateView()`, create another copy and past the below code.

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



   mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
            String image = dataSnapshot.child("image").getValue().toString();
            String status = dataSnapshot.child("status").getValue().toString();
            String thumb_image = 
             dataSnapshot.child("thumb_image").getValue().toString();

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        });
}
```